# How to use filter condition on multiple columns with not condition

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

My Data set looks like this :

[image]

I am using this filter :

```
df = df.filter(trim(col("AGE"))!="" & trim(col("PHONE"))!="")
```

I am getting an empty dataframe, I want the data without the record having name =G3

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Just use:  .filter(col("Name") != "G3")

Answer (score 2):

Please try filtering using below :-

```
df.filter(~((col('AGE').isNotNull()) & (col('PHONE').isNotNull()))).show()
```

OR

```
df.filter(~((col('AGE') != lit(None)) & (col('PHONE') != lit(None)))).show()
```

Please note the additional parentheses separating both conditions with '&' operator. And one set of parentheses for '~' (NOT operator)

Answer (score 0):

It is advisable to include not null checks when performing checks on columns, as the values in the columns may be null rather than an empty string(''). For instance, when checking the age and phone columns, you may want to consider adding not null checks to avoid errors that may arise from null values in these columns.

Below filter condition should help.

```python
df.filter(
    col("AGE").isNotNull() & col("PHONE").isNotNull() &
    trim(col("AGE")) != "" & trim(col("PHONE")) != ""
)
```